# How do I cleanup and remove a shed that is infested with rats?

Tags: shed, pest

A shed on the property of a small home in the California suburbs appears to have a significant rat infestation. Droppings are absolutely everywhere and do not appear desiccated, though I haven't seen a rat yet. I think they were eating some sort of grass feed that I've already thrown away. I think the shed and pretty much everything in it needs to be junked, but I'm not sure how to approach such a job. Do I just order a dumpster to my curb, put on a mask, and then proceed to empty and dismantle the shed? The shed is around 8x4x5 feet.

One complicating factor is that the electronic controller for the backyard sprinkler system is mounted and wired into a wall of the shed. I'd like to save it if that's easy to do, otherwise I can water the back lawn myself for the short term.

Thankfully no sign of infestation in the house yet.

Comment: Beside the droppings, do you want to get rid of the shed?  Is it in good condition besides the droppings?  If getting rid of it, the dumpster, a good mask and gloves should do.  What does wired into a wall mean?  The controller and maybe power connection can probably be placed on a pole/pipe.

Comment: Be careful. If the rats are living under the shed, and you remove the shed, the rats are going to look for a new home. Like your porch, or cellar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The week before the job, leave rat poison. The day of cleanup, use sprayer to soak everything with diluted bleach. You don't want any fecal dust flying around. Wear P100 mask and bag all the things you are throwing away. Add more bleach spray, making sure the shed is wet before you disassemble. Disconnect sprinkler controls. If there's AC 120v feed to shed, you might need an electrician to install a post and outdoor plug. Then take apart and throw into dumpster. BTW, if the shed is in good repair, no reason to demolish it once you clean and disinfect it.

Comment: Understood, thank you. The shed's pretty old -- it's at least from the 60s or 70s -- but it's still in good condition so I may end up saving it.